# how to add menu item from tags?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I am new in Drupal,
and I am creating  a library the library has subject, each subject select from a list that referenced to a taxonomy.

> I want each subject become an item in my menu and when click on it
>   show that tag result.

Comment: Do you want taxonomy terms from a vocabulary to show in the main menu? In that case check out https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu. Or do you mean that all nodes of the type library should be in the menu?

Comment: just a vocablery

Comment: Alright, have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my comment here as an answer also so this question can be closed.

If you want a taxonomy vocabulary and it's terms to be represented in a menu you can use the module [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). It synchronizes changes in your taxonomy tree to a menu of your choice.

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!